# Dependency injection into UITabBarController child ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

I am currently setting up a Tab Bar Application for iOS.

Normally, I would use an overridden method like *prepareforSeque* for dependency injection when changing viewControllers, but that method is not called when the UITabBarController changes its active child ViewController. How do I correctly do dependency injection into UITabBarController child ViewControllers?

Comment: UITabBarControllerDelegate protocol has a method called `tabBarController(_:didSelectViewController:)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the RootViewController's `viewDidLoad` you can iterate thru `childViewControllers` and find the various child controllers that you want and set the dependency to each of them. In this case the dependency will be available in viewDidLoad of the child view controllers. Tab bar instantiates the child view controller instances but does not load the view until its required.

Once the tab bar view controller is loaded  you can use the delegate methods to inject updated dependencies and use it in `viewDidAppear` because `viewDidLoad` will not get called once its selected in the tab bar.

Comment: Iterating through the view controllers works really well for solving the viewDidLoad() problem. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Mind sharing some code example? Simplified, pseudo, whatever :)

Answer (score 0):

With some extra research, I have come up with an answer. Thanks to [Will-m](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1450862/will-m) for the clue I needed. The current cavaet with this answer is that the first view loaded by the TabBarController will not get injected.

In order to inject data into ViewControllers from a UITabBarController, you need to do the following:

First, you need to set the RootViewController to be its own delegate when it loads.

> You don't necessarily need the controller class to be its own delegate
>   unless you need to inject the required data from another class directly to the UITabBarController.

You also need to declare the delegate class as compliant to [UITabBarControllerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html) protocol.

```
// Declare UITabBarControllerDelegate protocol
class RootViewController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Set class delegate to self
        self.delegate = self
    }
}
```

> You need to set the RootViewController's delegate because the
>   delegate's protocol contains an important method:
>   [tabBarController(_:shouldSelectViewController:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITabBarControllerDelegate/tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:). This method is
>   called when the RootViewController changes its active tab.

The "viewController" parameter of [tabBarController(_:shouldSelectViewController:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITabBarControllerDelegate/tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:) is the instance of the child ViewController which the TabBarController is switching to. Provided you have assigned a protocol to that ViewController (so that the compiler knows your variable is declared in the class), you can inject the variable into the child.

So add the function to the RootViewController class like this:

```
func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
    // Get your view controller using the correct protocol.
    // Use guard to make sure the correct type of viewController has been provided.
    guard let vc = viewController as? YourProtocol
        else { fatalError("wrong view controller type") }
    // Assign the protocol variable to whatever you want injected into the class instance.
    vc.VariableInYourProtocol = InjectedVariable
}
```

That's it. If you need to support controllers of different protocols, I might write something up on using a switch statement to do that. That
s just not something I've needed to work with as of yet.

Also, as a note, this method is applicable for CoreData practices in which only one managedObjectContext instance is passed between active ViewControllers. This method is used rather than retrieving different instances of the context directly from the application delegate for each ViewController.

Comment: Does this work if you need the InjectedVariable in viewDidLoad of the child view controller? What will happen if the viewDidLoad of the child view controller is called before the didSelectViewController delegate?   Another alternative is to use a static variable in your child view controller class and then set that variable before changing to the child view controller. Then you will have the dependency at any point in the child view controller. You can then set the variable to nil to indicate that you have consumed the dependency. Just another thought on how this could be done.

Comment: At the moment, no, but I'm looking into what other options are available if the variable is needed in viewDidLoad. At the moment,  tabBarController(_:didSelectViewController:) is called after the view is loaded. I'm going to try out your method and see if that works.

Comment: It depends on how your tab bar controller and child view controllers are set. Do you create the entire view controller hierarchy in storyboard or do you do it dynamically? If you do it in storyboard then the first view controller or in general the selectedIndex of tab bar controller is instantiated first. In this case delegate is not called. Delegate is called only when you select it manually. If you need the variable in viewDidLoad for other than the default child VC then you cannot set it in the delegate. You could iterate thru the child VCs and set the dependency.

Comment: Update: looks like the usage of the function [tabBarController(_:shouldSelectViewController:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITabBarControllerDelegate/tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:) was a better fit. It is called before the view is shown. The only caveat is the the first view the Tab Bar Controller shows is not injected.

Comment: Please look at my answer and see if that fits your solution. I think it will.

Comment: Sorry, looks like I was typing my comment and posted without seeing yours. I am using storyboard for my current project. The TabBarController is the RootViewController, and a CoreData instance is injected into said Controller from the AppDelegate. I'l definitely look at your answer and see how it goes. :)